# Acces variable from dataframe in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm newbie in Shiny, trying to make an app where I would like to make an overall statistical analysis (on time series) based on a dataset which I prior loaded. The problem is that I do not know how to "work" with a specific variable from dataset. I would like that the variable to be taken "dynamically", something like, datos[,2], but I do not know how to do this. Now I use attach function and then set y manually.
So my code for now is:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$RawData <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable({
      datos
    },
    options = list(lengthMenu=list(c(5,15,20),c('5','15','20')),pageLength=10,
                   initComplete = JS(
                     "function(settings, json) {",
                     "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'moccasin', 'color': '1c1b1b'});",
                     "}"),
                   columnDefs=list(list(className='dt-center',targets="_all"))
    ),
    # filter = "top",
    # selection = 'multiple',
    # style = 'bootstrap',
    # class = 'cell-border stripe',
    # rownames = FALSE,
    # colnames = TRUE
    ))
  
  
  testy=reactive({
    attach(datos)
    y=IMM
      
      if(input$primavar==1){
        
        probaty=adf.test(y)}
    
    else {
      if(input$primavar==2){
        
        probaty=pp.test(y)
      }
      else {
        probaty=kpss.test(y, null="Trend")
      }}
    probaty
  })
  
  output$Probay <- renderPrint({
    
    testy()
    
  })
  
  output$Conclusiony <- renderText({
    
    if(input$primavar==1 | input$primavar==2){
    if(testy()$p.value < 0.05){mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We keep the null hypothesis, the variable is not stationary"}
    mensaje}
      else {
      if(testy()$p.value > 0.05){mensaje="We accept the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the  variable is not stationary"}
      mensaje}
    
    
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 2nd column dynamically from `datos` you can use `[[`.

```
testy=reactive({
    y=datos[[2]]
    ....
    ....
    ....
  })
```

Comment: And I have another question :) If I uploaded an excel file and then from names(datos()) I set variable y, x1 and x2, and then I print the variables using something like ```df_sel=reactive({ req(input$y) df_sel= datos() %>% select(input$y)``` how can I acces de y variable to run the upper program? y=df_sel[[2]] does not work....Thank you in 
advance :)

Comment: @MariaRuxandra Can you ask that as a new question?